# PHP parallel/asynchronous SSH connections

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to open multiple connections (various devices) to run a command and get the output.
The problem is that i have to run them "all at once"/parallel. 
If i wait for one result and then to run the other one it takes way too long
and with a large number of devices that can go very bad.

I'm also using curl which I know that there is `curl_multi` and I was wondering if there was something similar with SSH for php.

I'm using Net_SSH2 for now.

Comment: I think you should lift this up to a more abstract level; take a look at the [process control extension (PCNTL)](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php).

Comment: Unfortunately i need this to be able to run on a Windows machine also

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use two PHP libraries: https://robo.li/tasks/Remote/#ssh and https://github.com/cheprasov/php-parallel. Your class method might be something similar to the example below:

```
function runParallelSSH() {

   $parallel = new Parallel(new ApcuStorage());

   foreach ($credentials as $user => $host) {
      $connection = sprintf('%s@%s', $user, $host);
      $connections[] = $connection;
      $Parallel->run($connection, function() {  
         $gitTask = $this->taskGitStack()
             ->checkout('master')
             ->pull();          
      });
   }

   $results = $parallel->wait($connections);

}
```

Comment: You bet! I currently use Parallel in Production code to crawl web sites easily launching 500 processes at 100K+ HTTP requests an hour

Answer (score 0):

Without using thirdparties like curl_multi you have to use PHP multithreading, for this you need an extension pthreads.

Look in the docs for [PHP threading](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)

The most interesting feature is using it like this (code modified from PHP.net)

```
class My extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        //curl_exec whatever
    }
}
$my = new My();

//start as many as you need
$my->start();

//wait for the threads to finnish and join one thread at a time with main-process-thread:
var_dump($my->join());:
```

Good Luck!